# What variable should i use to represent a small value?

Tags: convention

I am writing a computer code. I need to name a variable that represents a small offset.  Typically, I'd use `epsilon` or `delta` for those variable names, but those variables are already currently used for other things in the code.

**Question**:

1. What are some other Greek (or other) variables that are typically used to represent 'small' values in mathematics?

Comment: Why not epsilon$1$, epsilon$2$, and so on?  In any case, this really isn't a math problem.

Comment: *iota*, *smallNumber*, ...

Comment: `epsilon1`, `epsilon2`, etc is not appropriate because `epsilon` is being used as a threshold from a paper.  Using `epsilon` for a threshold and `epsilon1` for a small offset would be confusing and non-intuitive

Comment: Use capital delta if you have used small one or vice-versa

Comment: How about calling your variable `small_offset` then?